# How to execute a chained set of linux commands from python

Tags: python, shell

Following is an example of a shell command I'd like to execute verbatim. Any way to do this in python (i.e. similar to the %x{command} construct in ruby that will take anything you give it..

```
kill -9 $(ps -ef | grep java | grep TaskTracker | awk '{print $2}')
```

The trick here is it has chained pipes - so this does not play well AFAICT with for example popen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That command needs shell features including command substitution and pipes, so you should use `shell=True` in your `subprocess.call()` call. It should work fine as long as you're running it in a shell. So:

```
from subprocess import call

call("kill -9 $(ps -ef | grep java | grep TaskTracker | awk '{print $2}')",
      shell=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
import os
os.system(yourcommandshere)
```

Keep in mind for portability you should correctly ID which OS you're on.